# Variable replacement in dictionary

Tags: python, python-re

I have two formats:

```
queryString = "{'queryString': 'ipAddress:%ipAddress'}"
qs2 = "{'resourceNetworkInterface':[{'ipAddress': %ipAddress}]}"
```

They were originally dictionaries, which had been converted to string so as to generate the proper format code. I have been trying this regex pattern to replace the variable (`%ipAddress`) with `.format(IpAddress)` specifier. This is a part of a code generation functionality.

```
queryString = "{'queryString': 'ipAddress:%ipAddress'}"
qs2 = "{'resourceNetworkInterface':[{'ipAddress': %ipAddress}]}"
au_variable_pattern = "%[a-zA-Z$_][a-zA-Z0-9$_]*"


def insert_placeholder_for_au(match_obj):
    if match_obj.group() is not None:
        print(match_obj.group()[1:])
        return "'{}'.format(" + str(match_obj.group()[1:]) + ")"
        # return f'f"{{{match_obj.group()[1:]}}}"'


res_str = re.sub(au_variable_pattern,
                 insert_placeholder_for_au, qs2)
print(res_str)
```

The second `querystring` is getting generated correctly as:

```
{'resourceNetworkInterface':[{'ipAddress': '{}'.format(ipAddress)}]}
```

While the first queryString is not getting generated correctly:

```
{'queryString': 'ipAddress:'{}'.format(ipAddress)'}
```

I am trying to write a generalized solution that can work with variables inside any dictionary structure. How can this be done?

Comment: Why the second is wrong?

Comment: it shows as invalid syntax at runtime